# Why doesn't the while loop end with the extra "or" condition?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want the while loop to end when the condition "index >=maxlength".

The problem is it just says "Please Enter a String". The user enters a string, clicks "Enter" and it just stays there on the next line. Anything after the while loop does not get executed.

```
Please Enter a String: *ddddddddddd*
|
```

If I do not have the condition "index >=maxlength", the code works fine.

```
 public static int getaline( char message[], int maxlength ) {

    int index = 0;
    int character = 0;
    maxlength = 5;

    System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
    character = fgetc(System.in);

    while (character != '\n' || index >=maxlength){
        message[index] = (char) character;
        index++;
        character = fgetc(System.in);
    }
    if (index >= maxlength){
        System.out.println("Overflow");
    }
    System.out.println("The amount of elements in the array is" + index);
    return 0;           
}
```

Comment: What does `fgetc` do?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "File Get Character"...I assume, with it redirected to stdin ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is that some fancy c function?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Certainly reminds me of one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the loop to *end* when the index is greater than or equal to maxlength then you need the condition to be the **opposite**: it should loop *while* the index is *not* greater than or equal to maxlength.

```
while (character != '\n' && index < maxlength)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the while loop end with the extra “or” condition?

Because your test says to continue looping if `index` is **greater than** `maxlength`.

It is doing what you said, not what you meant.  Computers are like that :-)

---

> Is there a way to not allow the user to input any more characters after the max length?

It depends what you mean:

- If you are asking if there is a way to stop accepting characters after "max" have been read, the @JohnKugelman's answer says how.  (The problem is that the characters up to the end of line remain unread ... and if you then attempt to accept another item from the user, your application will see those characters first.  For example, if you called `getaline` again ...)
- If you want to ignore characters after "max" have been read, then you need to change the code so that it doesn't stop reading at "max", but it only adds them to `message` if `index` is less than the max.
- If you want to stop the user from entering the characters, then there is no easy way to do it.  And maybe, no way at all.  (You most likely do not want to try to do this because it will introduce various other problems.)

Comment: Is there a way to not allow the user to input any more characters after the max length? <an addition to the question>

Comment: Thank you. I took your advice for the first one and I applied "null" to unread characters exceeding the max length. I tried to add another condition to the while loop, CTRL+D, in order to exit the terminal. Example "while (character != '\n' && index <maxlength || character != EOF) but then I ran into the same problem as I had for this question. Am I calling the CTRL+D incorrectly?

Comment: When you type ^D at an application from the console, that causes the input stream to end after the prior characters have been consumed.  That will cause `InputStream.read()` to return `-1`.  If your `fgetc` method is returning a `char`, then comparing the result of `fgetc` with `-1` will always give `false`.